# copying array of double using copy constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, copy-constructor

i want to make copy constructor for my class which has array of double as private member\
how can i write copy constructor i have tried following code and it results in error

```
    class My_class
        {
        private:
            double dp [500];
        public:
            My_class(const My_class & c1)
        {
            //error the following line why i cant use arrayname as a pointer?
            dp =new double[500];
            for(int i=0;i<500;i++)
                *(dp+i)=c1.dp[i];

        }
}
```

how can i make this copy constructor work?

Comment: "why i cant use arrayname as a pointer?" Because two are not equivalent

Comment: "why i cant use arrayname as a pointer" - because arrays aren't pointers; they just act like they are in specific situations (none of which apply to what you're doing).

Comment: You don't need `new`, and you don't need a copy constructor at all. A compiler generated copy constructor will work perfectly fine.

Comment: Sidenote: You use `*(dp+i)` in one case and `dp[i]` in the other. Why not use the latter in both cases and do `dp[i] = c1.dp[i];`?

Answer (score 2):

```
dp =new double[500];
```

That code is redundant and wrong. Because you already have a member `dp` as an array of doubles.

Remove that line, and your constructor should work:

```
            for(int i=0;i<500;++i)
                *(dp+i)=c1.dp[i];
```

But that's redundant, too. Because your class has an array member (not a pointer), then a default copy constructor would do all the work (ie memberwise copy) for you.

Usually you only need to worry about copy constructor (and copy assignment etc.) when you have a pointer member - in that case the default (compiler-generated) copy constructor would do the so-called shallow-copy which is incorrect, and so you have to create your own deep-copy, or better with something called move-operation.

Answer (score 1):

Although you don't need one as the compiler generated one is perfectly fine in this case, were there a need you could have used `memmove` or `std::copy` for this.

```
double array[500];
double dest[500];

std::copy(begin(array), end(array), begin(dest));

::memmove(dest, array, sizeof(double)*500);
```

Comment: With any reasonable C++ library implementation, `std::copy` will turn into a call to `memmove` whenever that's appropriate. So stick with `std::copy`. +1.

Answer (score 0):

You declared the dp array as member variable so there is no need to allocate its memory using new operator just use the array directly

```
My_class(const My_class & c1)
{
    //error the following line why i cant use arrayname as a pointer?
    //dp =new double[500]; << no need to do this
    for(int i=0;i<500;i++)
        dp[i]=c1.dp[i];
```

}